# Infer readonly record values when used in a spread type

Tags: typescript

If I create a function with some parameters, where each parameter is its own generic parameter and the parameter is marked `Readonly`, it's possible to call this function with an object literal and infer both the keys and values:

```
function foo<A extends Record<string, string>, B extends Record<string, string>>(
  a: Readonly<A>, 
  b: Readonly<B>
): void {
 // whatever
}

foo({a: 'hello'}, {b: 'world'}); // A and B are inferred to {a: 'hello'}, {b: 'world'}
```

However, I'm trying to generalize this function so that it can take an arbitrary number of arguments, so instead I give it a single generic parameter `T` which is an array of records:

```
function foo2<T extends Array<Readonly<Record<string, string>>>>(...args: T): void {
}

foo2({a: 'hello'}, {b: 'world'})
```

However, even though each array element is `Readonly`, this is only inferred as `{a: string}, {b: string}`. The literal values of each record are lost.

Is there a way to declare `foo2` so that it keeps `hello` and `world` as literals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [`const`-modifier](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/51865) for type parameters. In functions, methods, or constructor invocations literal expressions will be inferred with the most precise type possible, similar to a [`const`-assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions).

```
declare function foo2<const T extends Array<Readonly<Record<string, string>>>>(
  ...args: T
): void;

foo2({ a: "hello" }, { b: "world" });

// inferred as [{ readonly a: "hello"; }, { readonly b: "world"; }]
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtVJxwCYAeMPAZw3gBV4QAPDEVYC+AQRhigE8SASiCjA8EfkPIxgJKjCyoA5gBp4chYoB82zQAoAUPHgA6U7EUUAXLX0BKawDccWYAG59+xISK6A3vChrACIACxAICBwg+ABfVX8AI2CAdxwYCGBomNt3AHpc+AA9AH59IA)

---

If you don't want to upgrade to [TypeScript 5.0](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-0.html#const-type-parameters) the alternative approach is to use a `const`-assertion on every single argument. However, this is a bit inconvenient, easy to forget, and the reason why `const` type parameters were introduced in the first place.

```
declare function foo2<T extends Array<Readonly<Record<string, string>>>>(
  ...args: T
): void;

foo2({ a: "hello" } as const, { b: "world" } as const);

// inferred as [{ readonly a: "hello"; }, {readonly b: "world"; }]
```

Comment: Thanks, this notation was indeed new to me and seems to address the problem in a good way - HOWEVER, it seems this is only available in TypeScript 5. Ah well, it was time to upgrade those 100 components anyway...

Comment: I expanded my answser for the sake of completeness.